# Mongoose how to listen for collection changes

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I need to build a mongo updater process to dowload mongodb data to local IoT devices (configuration data, etc.)

My goal is to watch for some mongo collections in a fixed interval (1 minute, for example). If I have changed a collection (deletion, insertion or update) I will download the full collection to my device. The collections will have no more than a few hundred simple records, so it´s gonna not be a lot of data to download.

Is there any mechanism to find out a collection has changed since last pool ? What mongo features should be used in that case ?

Comment: what have you tried so far? We can't really help you with something so generic.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

To listen for changes to your MongoDB collection, set up a Mongoose `Model.watch`.

```js
const PersonModel = require('./models/person')

const personEventEmitter = PersonModel.watch()

personEventEmitter.on('change', change => console.log(JSON.stringify(change)))

const person = new PersonModel({name: 'Thabo'})
person.save()

// Triggers console log on change stream
// {_id: '...', operationType: 'insert', ...}
```

> **Note:** This functionality is only available on a MongoDB *Replicaset*

See [Mongoose Model Docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#model_Model.watch) for more:

If you want to listen for changes to your **DB**, use `Connection.watch`.

See [Mongoose Connection Docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/connection.html#connection_Connection-watch) for more

These functions listen for [Change Events](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/change-events/) from [MongoDB Change Streams](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/an-introduction-to-change-streams) as of v3.6

Comment: Thank you. I have been searching for this for days......!

Answer (score 3):

I think best solution would be using post update middleware.

You can read more about that here
http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html

Comment: I agree, this doesn't require you to setup any replica sets (Which might be an overkill or a pain in the ass sometimes).  Just create post middleware for all the events you want to watch on the collection. Create, update, delete, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same demand on an embedded that works quite autonomously, and it is always necessary to auto adjust your operating parameters without having to reboot your system.

For this I created a configuration manager class, and in its constructor I coded a "parameter monitor", which checks the database only the parameters that are flagged for it, of course if a new configuration needs to be monitored, I inform the config -manager in another part of the code to reload such an update.

As you can see the process is very simple, and of course can be improved to avoid overloading the config-manager with many updates and also prevent them from overlapping with a very small interval.

Since there are many settings to be read, I open a cursor for a query as soon as the database is connected and opened. As data streaming sends me new data, I create a [proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) for it so that it can be manipulated according to the type and internal details of Config-manager. I then check if the property needs to be monitored, if so, I call an inner-function called watch that I created to handle this, and it queries the subproject of the same name to see what default time it takes to check in the database by updates, and thus registers a timeout for that task, and each check recreates the timeout with the updated time or interrupts the update if watch no longer exists.

```
 this.connection.once('open', () => {
      let cursor = Config.find({}).cursor();
      cursor.on('data', (doc) => {

        this.config[doc.parametro] = criarProxy(doc.parametro, doc.valor);

        if (doc.watch) {
          console.log(sprintf("Preparando para Monitorar %s", doc.parametro));

          function watch(configManager, doc) {
            console.log("Monitorando parametro: %s", doc.parametro);
            if (doc.watch)  setTimeout(() => {
                Config.findOne({
                  parametro: doc.parametro
                }).then((doc) => {
                  console.dir(doc);
                  if (doc) {
                    if (doc.valor != configManager.config[doc.parametro]) {
                      console.log("Parametro monitorado: %(parametro)s, foi alterado!", doc);
                      configManager.config[doc.parametro] = criarProxy(doc.parametro, doc.valor);
                    } else
                      console.log("Parametro monitorado %{parametro}s, não foi alterado", doc);

                     watch(configManager, doc);
                  } else
                    console.log("Verifique o parametro: %s")
                })

              },
              doc.watch)
          } 
            watch(this, doc);
        }
      });
      cursor.on('close', () => {
        if (process.env.DEBUG_DETAIL > 2) console.log("ConfigManager closed cursor data");
        resolv();
      });
      cursor.on('end', () => {
        if (process.env.DEBUG_DETAIL > 2) console.log("ConfigManager end data");
      });
```

As you can see the code can improve a lot, if you want to give suggestions for improvements according to your environment or generics please use the gist: https://gist.github.com/carlosdelfino/929d7918e3d3a6172fdd47a59d25b150